# Get a substring from url jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working a one-page website that uses Jquery and ajax. Because it is a one page website, its url is always something like `mydomain.com/#contact`. Now I have successfully made an ajax call and want to refresh the page and scroll to a particular section of the page with a different id say, `mydomain.com/#home`. In order to do this, I will have to get the current url using `document.URL` (let's say it returns `mydomain.com/#contact`), then I remove `/#contact` and replace it with `/#home`. 
I know I can replace `/#contact` with `/#home` by simply concatenating it with `+` but I don't know the Jquery function (if any) to remove the `/#contact`.

Thanks so much for any help

Comment: this is an XY to the MAX!

Comment: Hi @freedomn-m, My question may have been incomplete or poorly presented but I thought at least the main idea will remain clear. 'refreshing the page' as i said was not the central point in my question. I am well aware from the first day I started learning ajax that the whole point of it is not to refresh the page.. and yeah, sometimes we may need to tweak the laws and traditions of some programming technologies depending on our need at the moment.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to do, as @Jamiec mentioned, it looks like you're trying to do X by doing Y and then failing to do Y and asking about Y instead of asking about X.  This part "scroll to a section" can be done with: `$("#contact").scrollTop(0);`

Answer (score 4):

Simply set the hash, you don't need to evaluate the existing URL:

```
window.location.hash = "Home";
```